# smartctl not working from cron job

Tags: php, linux, debian

I have a problem with `smartctl`

Have updated from version 5.4 to the lastest version 6.4.. No change.. Same issue

It works fine when running the command `smartctl -H /dev/sda` directly from the command line

But when running the command from a cronjob its not working as it should. Here you can see the cron job settings.. Its running as `root`

The job is running every 60 sec while testing and the command doesn't return anything. Only the timestamp is written to the file.

But if I press the button "Run now" then the command works?! Very strange!? In the code you can see that the output is written to a file.. The output is empty

Another thing.. When the job is automated only one timestamp is written to the file.. Two timestamps should be written?

[image]

```
function check_dev($dev){
    $status_ok = "=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===\nSMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED";
    
    $output = shell_exec('smartctl -H '.$dev);
    
    file_put_contents('/var/www/hdd_out.txt', gmdate("M d Y H:i:s", time())."\n".$output, FILE_APPEND);
    
    if(strpos($output, $status_ok) !== false){
        echo "$dev OK!\n";
        
        return true;
    }
    else{
        echo "$dev ERROR!\n";
        
        return false;
    }   
}

if(check_dev('/dev/sda') && check_dev('/dev/sdb')){
    $status = 0;
}
else{
    $status = 1;
}
```

## output file

```
Jun 17 2015 10:17:01
Jun 17 2015 10:18:01
Jun 17 2015 10:19:01
Jun 17 2015 10:20:01
Jun 17 2015 10:21:01
Jun 17 2015 10:22:01
Jun 17 2015 10:23:01
Jun 17 2015 10:24:01
Jun 17 2015 10:25:01
Jun 17 2015 10:26:01
Jun 17 2015 10:27:01
Jun 17 2015 10:28:01
Jun 17 2015 10:29:01
Jun 17 2015 10:29:54 # here I manually pressed "Run now"
smartctl 6.4 2014-09-29 r3990 [x86_64-linux-2.6.32-5-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

Jun 17 2015 10:29:54 # here I manually pressed "Run now"
smartctl 6.4 2014-09-29 r3990 [x86_64-linux-2.6.32-5-amd64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

Jun 17 2015 10:30:01
Jun 17 2015 10:31:01
Jun 17 2015 10:32:01
Jun 17 2015 10:33:01
```

Comment: Please explain what the output file contains. Are the timestamps with no program output the result of minute cron runs, while the ones with output the result of you running the job yourself?

Comment: output file is added

Comment: I see that it is added, but I don't understand the output, in particular what causes the empty lines. Generally in a cron job, you will want to specify the full path to the executable, like /usr/bin/php and `/usr/bin/smartctl` but smartctl may be in a different path like `/usr/sbin/smartctl`

Comment: Oh, now I understand - you are writing the timestamps with PHP. That means smartctl isn't producing output, and it may be because it isn't found at all. `shell_exec()` cannot retrieve error output, while `exec()` can. http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php You will need to read its error code.

Comment: its working after adding the absolute path :) create an answer

Comment: Okay, answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user and environment under which cron runs is often much more limited than the environment you're used to when logged into a TTY. In particular, the `$PATH` environment variable may be different or even empty.

It is therefore recommended to use the full path to any executable you call in the script. Since the cron script *is* running, the `php` executable is being found in the cron task itself, but the `smartctl` may not be found inside the PHP script.

Locate the full path to `smartctl` using `which smartctl`, then modify the PHP script to use the full path. It is likely `/usr/bin/smartctl` or `/usr/sbin/smartctl`.

Using `shell_exec()` makes it difficult to retrieve error information from commands called. Instead, using [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and specifying the 3rd argument `$return_var` to capture the return code, along with the `$output` array may be more helpful.